# CKEditor JS API insert internal file link (MediaWiki WYSIWYG extension)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'd like to use CKEditor's Javascript API to insert an internal file link into the text being edited.
(Same as when you click on the Link icon and select "Internal link to an image or a file")

I've tried using insertText and insertHtml, the problem is the special characters ([, ], etc.) are escaped.

```
var inst = CKEDITOR.instances.wpTextbox1;
inst.insertText('[[:File:'+file.name+']]');
inst.insertHtml('[[:File:'+file.name+']]', '', '', '' );
```

I've tried switching the mode of the editor but it seems insertText and insertHtml only work in wysiwyg mode.

```
var inst = CKEDITOR.instances.wpTextbox1;
var oldmode = inst.mode;
inst.mode = 'source';
inst.insertText('[[:File:'+file.name+']]');
inst.insertHtml('[[:File:'+file.name+']]', '', '', '' );
inst.mode = oldmode;
```

What does the "Link" button actually do for this to work?

If the Link button can do it, I believe so should I, using the JS API...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem has more layers than I initially thought.

I also forgot to mention that this is CKEditor included in WYSIWYG extension for MediaWiki.

So we have

- MediaWiki and its API (webservice)
- CKEditor (as MediaWiki extension) and its JS API
- CKEditor plugins (just like Mediawiki uses extensions, CKEditor can have plugins)

Now, when you are in WYSIWYG mode of CKEditor you essentially create HTML in the background. When saving (or switching to source mode), CKEditor translates this to wikitext.

So, for example, if you like the final Wiki document to contain an image, and you'd like to add it via the CKEditor JS API you have to use `insertHtml()`:

```
insertHtml('<img src="" _fck_mw_filename="x"');
```

The crux here is the special attribute `_fck_mw_filename` which is used by CKEditor. (found in PATH_TO_MEDIAWIKI/extensions/WYSIWYG/ckeditor/_source/plugins/mediawiki/plugin.js)

Using this attribute tells CKEditor to generate the appropriate wikitext

```
[[File:x]]
```

(x will need to be the canonical name of the file)

So the answer here is: You cannot write Wikitext into the WYSIWYG editor, you will have to write whatever the WYSIWYG editor expects in order to generate the correct wikitext afterwards.

---

There is more to this, but it is out of the scope of this answer.

In fact, for the *initial* display of the inserted image you will need to set the `src` attribute.

However, you cannot set an absolute URL. You either have to temporarily insert the base64 encoded image (as when you copy/paste) or insert a *local* link (in the form `/images/a/b/image.png`). Otherwise (using the full URL), it would create a link to an external URL (even though it's internal) and not show the image itself.

Finally, uploading the image itself is a completely different task, you will have to create an upload script that you can trigger using an XMLHttpRequest for example in order to wield MediaWiki's API to perform the upload (just putting in the filesystem is not enough, as it has to be in the database too etc.) Obviously the image must have been uploaded before being able to reference it here.